# Android multi-threading - Timing of playing sounds & responses

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio

Really new to this stuff so bear with me!

In my app I need to prompt the user to respond via button press to a noise, and record the response if it happens only while the sound is playing. I also need to have a variable sound presentation time, and variable time between the sounds...

The issue that I am facing is that I need a way to issue a delay between the presentations of the sounds, and have a delay between a sound play and sound stop command. I understand that to use a wait() I need to use another thread so that I don't pause the UI thread.

I need to some help as to which is the most elegant way of doing this? At the moment I have this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.start:


            presentTone(1000,60,2000,"l");
            // I need to insert a delay here, or in the presentTone method body 
            break;
```

and my presentTone method is this:

```
private void presentTone(int frequency,int amplitude,final int length,String side){


// GETTING THE CORRECT AMPLITUDE LEVEL

    // Find the correction level as a float
    correctionDB = calibrationOffsets.get(frequency + "L");

    // Decibels for 5 dB drops
    volLog = (float) (Math.pow(10,((amplitude-100)/20)));

    // Multiply the decibels correction with the presentation level to get the calibrated level if the offset is positive
    volLog = (float) (volLog*(Math.pow(10,((correctionDB)/20))));

    // Check to see if the system is capable of the 80 dB desired level
    if (volLog>1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Over Error - System is not capable of this amplitude level!" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


//PICKING THE CORRECT HEADPHONE SIDE TO PLAY

    volLogL = volLog;
    volLogR = volLog;

    if (side.toLowerCase().contains("l")){
        volLogR = (float) 0.0;
    }else if (side.toLowerCase().contains("r")){
        volLogL = (float) 0.0;
    }

//PLAYING THE TONE

    // Playing the tone
    mp.reset();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,idReferences.get(freq_selection));
    mp.setVolume(volLogL, volLogR);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
            }
            try {
                mp.start();{


//* I need to add a delay here, so I think I need to run the whole "Playing the tone" section in another thread?



                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I need the new thread to be within the presentTone method, so that I can start the playback, delay for a time, then stop. I also need to feed back a boolean for whether the sound is playing so that I can handle user response.

Apologies if what I am asking is unclear, I'm doing my best to make it obvious! I'd appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add comments in your code as to which section you're trying to execute in another thread or what multi-threading task you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Alexis, -*deleted previous comment for clarity*- I think I need the "playing of the tone" part to be in another thread so that I can play the tone, wait, then stop the tone. I assume I will be able to pass a boolean back that states whether the tone is playing at that time or not to handle the user response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little threading example which you can try and use to implement in your own situation. For example, the `while` loop here is only controlled by the active state of the `TaskObject`, but you can add your own conditions, or add methods to the `Task` to control  the looping.

The `Task` would be the equivalent of your `presentTone(...)` method, which is the task you want to run in another thread.

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    private final TaskObject object;
    private int executionTick = 0;

    public Task(final TaskObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.object.start();
        try {
            while (this.object.isActive()) {
                if (this.executionTick == 10) {
                    this.object.stop();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(this.executionTick++ + ": " + this.object.getName());
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `TaskObject` would be the object managed by the task. Here, I created a generic one, but that would be the equivalent of your sound, tone or media source.

```
public class TaskObject {
    private String name;
    private boolean active = false;

    public TaskObject(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void start() {
        this.active = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.active = false;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return this.active;
    }
}
```

And here's the test.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The object we want to manage or track with the task.
        TaskObject executedObject = new TaskObject("Foo");

        // Executing the task.
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new Task(executedObject));
        executor.shutdown();

        // Wait in this thread and change the name of the object.
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
        executedObject.setName("New Name");

        // Wait for the end of the task.
        executor.awaitTermination(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0: Foo
1: Foo
2: Foo
3: New Name
4: New Name
5: New Name
6: New Name
7: New Name
8: New Name
9: New Name
```

Please note that this is only a generic example for you to better understand how to approach your multi-threading implementation, it's not to copy-paste! :)

Feel free to ask if you have any question!

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexis! One question; do you have a bit more documentation for this, or a simple guide? Looks like what I am after, but it looks like I need to do some reading on the background and fundamentals...

Comment: @LeeDavison I found this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html) to be a good starting point, but you can always take a look at the [Official Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) on executors.

Comment: @LeeDavison A good thing too is to experiment by yourself with simple situations to get more at ease, and then implement it with more complex code. My answer is an example of that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.start:

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public voir run(){
            Thread.sleep(_time_);
            presentTone(1000,60,2000,"l");
          }
        }).start();
        break;
```

This should work.

This way it will not pause the main thread.

Comment: Can I also try to implement this within my method body? the reason for this is that I can then start the sound, pause, then stop the sound, and have that inside the method cleanly? Thanks a lot for your help so far